# Why does JSTL parseNumber parse 1000.0 to 10000?

Tags: parsing, types, jstl

I have an input form where I want to insert some numbers and calculate some results. So my input field looks like

```
<fmt:parseNumber var = "a" type = "number" 
    value = "${object.someAttribute}" integerOnly = "true"/>

<input type="number" name="someAttribute" required pattern="[0-9]" value="${a}" />
```

**I want to do following**: at first visit, a user should insert a number (Integer). In the calculation, all values are `Double` to prevent casting side effects. When the site is refreshed / the user wants to repeat the calculation, the input field should be preset with the recently used value. Therefore I tried `fmt:parseNumber` to parse the `Double` value from the object to an `Integer`.

At first try I omitted `integerOnly = "true"` but got an Error (as '`1000.0`' is not a valid input, that's understandable as I specified `pattern="[0-9]"`).

But with `integerOnly` set, it changes the value from `1000.0` to `10000`. What am I doing wrong? How could I parse it to achieve my goal?

Comment: If you are using EL 2.2+, you can simply use `${yourDouble.intValue()}`. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

Comment: @JasperdeVries thank you. I'm using JSTL 1.2 and it works perfectly. Could you put it in an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using EL 2.2+, you can simply convert a double to integer by invoking a non-getter method on your `Double` object:

```
${yourDouble.intValue()}
```

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info